# What is this type of fixed point called?

Tags: terminology, nonlinear-system

After numerically solving the following differential equations:

$$v'(t)=\frac{-\frac{1}{3} v(t)^3+v(t)-\omega (t)}{\tau } $$ $$  \omega '(t)= \frac{a+v(t)}{\tau}$$

at $a=1,\tau=0.2$ and taking $t$ from 0 to 10, I get this phase space plot:

[image]

The fixed point $(-1,-\frac23)$ is similar to an attracting focus, in that all nearby trajectories get attracted to it in a spiral. Note that the above plot is of a finite set of time steps, and there are no limit cycles here.

However, as one gets closer and closer to the fixed point, it starts behaving more and more like a center in the sense that trajectories seem to form almost closed loops. Basically, the trajectories are reaching the fixed point, but asymptotically.

As the nature of a fixed point is determined by the behavior of the trajectories in its immediate neighborhood, is this fixed point a center? Or is it  a stable focus? Or is it called something else entirely? (I've been calling it a "limit point")

Comment: I didn't read your description too carefully, but from the picture you may have a globally attracting limit cycle. You may want to look up Hopf bifurcations.

Comment: @nayrb I know what a hopf bifurcation is :) However, there is no _cycle_ here. All points are attracted to $(-1,-\frac23)$; for a limit cycle we need a loop where the points inside are attracted outwards and vice versa. We don't have that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stability analysis can enlighten you here. Your system is determined by the a system of equation
\begin{align}
 \dot{\nu} = f(\nu,\omega)\\
 \dot{\omega} = g(\nu,\omega)
\end{align}
with a jacobian
\begin{align}
 J = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1-\nu^2}{\tau} & -\frac{1}{\tau}\\ \frac{1}{\tau} & 0\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
Near the fixed point $(\nu^*,\omega^*)=(-1,-2/3)$, it evaluates to

\begin{align}
 J^* = \begin{bmatrix}0 & -\frac{1}{\tau}\\ \frac{1}{\tau} & 0\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

with eigenvalues $\lambda=\pm i/\tau$. So, what can be said about this fixed point? It is a **marginal case**: eigenvalues have null real parts. In the case of interest the fixed point is called a *center* [Strogatz 2000, Nonlinear dynamics and chaos].

Comment: Ah, so we can call it a center even if there are no actual points where it really behaves like a center (for normal centers there is a non-infinitesimal region around the point where we have closed loops, whereas here there are no closed loops at all.). Is there any special terminology for this type of center?

Comment: Convergence toward pure centers is always asymptotic, so you don't have a special case here. Only a negative real part will lead to faster than asymptotic convergence (in which case the point is sometime called a hyperbolic center).

Comment: Oh, I see. Till now I've seen centers that are pretty nice (i.e. normal Hamiltonian systems) and then an assortment of focii/nodes/limit cycles. So I assumed they were the norm. Thanks!